# Slicing Data with Calculated Field in Tableau 10.3

Tags: tableau-api

I am making a donut chart in Tableau 10.3. 
I have a Calculated Field called % Market Share where I have IF Condition working for different years.
The formula I have used is as follows

```
IF ATTR(YEAR([Date]) = 2016) THEN COUNTD([Complete Address])/1461
ELSEIF ATTR(YEAR([Date]) = 2017) THEN COUNTD([Complete Address])/1640
END
```

When I am trying to display only the top 10 Broking firms basis % Market Share, I am unable to do so because the calculated field is not appearing in the pop up window for filtering Broking Firms.
[image: Please find attached the image for better clarity]

Comment: I couldn't find any solid documentation on this, but some calculated fields like attribute or aggregates of a measure will not appear as an option. I would recommend looking into level of detail calculations or figuring out if there is a way to use table calculations to filter in the same manner.

Comment: This ought to be feasible. Can you post a sample workbook somewhere? maybe on Tableau public or in Tableau's forums. Why the hard coded denominators?